# Smart quotes for Italian language

Tags: org-mode, org-export

With the language set to English the smart quotes work out of the box:

```
#+LANGUAGE: en
#+OPTIONS: ':t

This is a "test".
```

LaTeX: ``` This is a ``test''. ```
HTML: `This is a “test”.`

Also with other languages (e.g. German, French, Spanish, ...) they work, but not with **Italian**:

```
#+LANGUAGE: it
#+OPTIONS: ':t

This is a "test".
```

LaTeX: `This is a "test".`
HTML: `This is a "test".`

Is there a way to add support for Italian smart quotes? Or otherwise a way to add custom support for smart quotes.

Since Italian smart quotes are indeed equal to English smart quotes another solution could be, if possible, to use English smart quotes with Italian language.

Comment: See the variable `org-export-smart-quotes-alist` which AFAICT does not have an entry for `it` so you get the default. You can submit a bug report to the Org mode mailing list, or (better) submit a patch to fix the omission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the patch:

```
[PATCH] ox: Italian smart quotes

* ox.el (org-export-smart-quotes-alist): Added support for italian smart quotes.
---
 lisp/ox.el | 6 ++++++
 1 file changed, 6 insertions(+)

diff --git a/lisp/ox.el b/lisp/ox.el
index eb12b68d7..5fe894569 100644
--- a/lisp/ox.el
+++ b/lisp/ox.el
@@ -5476,6 +5476,12 @@ transcoding it."
      (secondary-closing
       :utf-8 "‘" :html "&lsquo;" :latex "\\grq{}" :texinfo "@quoteleft{}")
      (apostrophe :utf-8 "’" :html "&rsquo;"))
+    ("it"
+     (primary-opening :utf-8 "“" :html "&ldquo;" :latex "``" :texinfo "``")
+     (primary-closing :utf-8 "”" :html "&rdquo;" :latex "''" :texinfo "''")
+     (secondary-opening :utf-8 "‘" :html "&lsquo;" :latex "`" :texinfo "`")
+     (secondary-closing :utf-8 "’" :html "&rsquo;" :latex "'" :texinfo "'")
+     (apostrophe :utf-8 "’" :html "&rsquo;"))
     ("no"
      ;; https://nn.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitatteikn
      (primary-opening
-- 
2.32.0
```

I sent it to the mailing list, but I don't see it in https://orgmode.org/list/, maybe I have done something wrong.

**EDIT**
Finally is here: https://orgmode.org/list/MgqQyHa--3-2@tuta.io/T/#u

Comment: Yup, I just saw it - thanks!